# How to judge whether a topic is orderly or unordered in RocketMQ?

Tags: rocketmq

How to judge whether a topic is orderly or unordered? Can I view it from the RocketMQ-Console? I did not find the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 0):

messages in topic are orderly once rocketmq stored in commit log, like queue.
they will behave differently in orderly-consuming and concurrently-consuming(un-orderly).

let's take java for example:

- [orderly consuming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBsMU.png)
- [concurrently consuming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHHA0.png)